# Laravel Blade Template throws error "Unexpected end of the file"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I get the following error from Laravel on Blade:

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN)
```

Here is What I've done.

My Controller:

```
class AdminPostingController extends AdminBaseController
{
    protected $layout = "Admin.master";

    function postNew()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make("Admin.index");
    }
}
```

My Admin.index File:

```
@extends("Admin.master')

@section("content")
    <p>Example P</p>
@stop
```

Here is Admin.master.blade.php:

```
@yield("content")
```

Comment: What are the file names used for each files and what is the path for your view files ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in Admin.index file.

Instead of `@extends("Admin.master')` it should be `@extends("Admin.master")`. It should fix the problem.

EDIT: In case my original answer wasn't clear enough, the problem was that you had double quotes at the start of the string and single quote at the end, hence the syntax error.

Comment: `Instead of @extends("Admin.master') it should be @extends("Admin.master")`, Can you explain the difference?